Should these indexes be merged?
Here are 2 examples with 2 indexes each, assuming all of these indexes have high usage should they be merged or kept separate? My first thought is only example #2 should have its indexes merged.
Example #1:
CREATE INDEX [ix_Orders_1] 
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([cancelled], [approved], [denied], [saved])   
INCLUDE ([total], [subTotal], [tax])

CREATE INDEX [ix_Orders_2] 
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([cancelled], [isQuote]) 
INCLUDE ([dateStamp], [userId])

Example #2:
CREATE INDEX [ix_Products_1] 
ON [dbo].[Products] ([itemNumber])  
INCLUDE ([altItemNumber], [description]) 

CREATE INDEX [ix_Products_2] 
ON [dbo].[Products] ([itemNumber], [showPrice]) 
INCLUDE ([level_1], [level_2], [level_3], [level_4])

In example #1 since the second columns in both differ, I assume they should be kept as 2 indexes.
In example #2, could the indexes be merged into the following and keep its performance?
CREATE INDEX [ix_Products_3] 
ON [dbo].[Products] ([itemNumber], [showPrice]) 
INCLUDE ([altItemNumber], [description], [level_1], [level_2], [level_3], [level_4]) 


SQL Server 2008 has been formally end of life since 2019. That means it hasn't had any security updates in more than 5 years. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

I am aware but it's not under my control and this is what I have to work with right now.

To properly answer the question, we would have to see the SQL for all of the queries that access the table along with posts of each of their execution plans (Paste the PLan). That is probably be to broad of a question for this forum. In general terms, the answer is: No. Do not combine them unless you know that your queries can make as efficient use of the combined index as with the separate indexes. Indexes are more than just a collection of columns. The column order matters with the first column being the most critical in narrowing a search.

... On the other hand, that does not mean you shouldn't look into reducing and combining indexes. It just needs to be done with an understanding of how these indexes are used.  For example, if to need to look up a customer by name, an index on (LastName, FirstName) might be useful. If if you need to look up a customer by store, an index starting with StoreId would be useful. If you only want active customers in both cases, adding IsActive to the end of the indexed column list on both indexes may improve performance. ...

...What you should not do is combine these indexes into a single index on (LastName, FirstName, StoreId, IsActive). This may still support efficient lookups by name, but it will not support an efficient lookup by store, since StoreId is not the first indexed column. This might result in a less efficient "index scan" instead of the more efficient "index seek". Perhaps "How to Think Like the Database Engine" may be worth a look.

As for the specific cases you mentioned, I would agree that Example #2 is very likely a good candidate for a merge.  The first column ItemNumber should immediately narrow the search to a relatively small umber of rows in both cases where your queries filter for that column. Example #1 is a harder call. I expect that filtering on cancelled = 0 does little to limit the scope of the search, so the remaining indexed columns still play an important role in narrowing those searches.

Example 1 is rather interesting, because the implication of the column names in the key (not the include) is that these are bit columns, so using them as key columns isn't very useful in most cases. We really do need to see both the full table definitions and the queries that use this table (along with plans), otherwise it's really hard to give a definite answer.

@Charlieface Hm BlitzIndex estimates a significant performance even on these bit columns

@TN I thought example #2 might be straightforward, since the 1st index only uses itemNumber in the key, and the first column of the 2nd index uses itemNumber then index lookups for the 1st index can just use the 2nd index instead?

At first glance Example 2 is very straightforward. Any query currently seeking on itemNumber or ordering on itemNumber can equally well use an index on itemNumber, showPrice as long as it still covers all the columns, as the index is larger it may incur some greater number of logical reads though. One edge case to consider for non unique indexes is that SQL Server silently adds the CI key or RID to the end of the key, so you are really comparing ( [itemNumber], ProductId ) vs ( [itemNumber], [showPrice], ProductId ) as an example. (Assuming CI key of ProductId)

In which case a query like WHERE itemNumber = @itemNumber ORDER BY ProductId would be able to avoid a sort operation with the first index but not the combined index

If the index keys in the example #1 cases are bit they might be better implemented as a set of filtered indexes. At least filtered indexes were supported in 2008.

The composition of an index key is actually a vector, which means that the order of the columns of this index key is very important for it to be efficient in searching, otherwise it will be ignored...
But the "strength" of the search is less on the final columns of the key than the very first ones, because each column that follows the previous one over-filters the already filtered results... This means that the last column filtering the least, in the case of a multi-column key can be ignored if it is put in the INCLUDE clause specific to SQL Server and recently to PostGreSQL...
In other words, in your example #1, you could try the following synthesis:
CREATE INDEX [ix_Orders_1]
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([cancelled]))
INCLUDE ([total], [subTotal], [tax], [approved], [denied], [saved], [dateStamp], [userId])

But I'm not sure that it is really useful. It's up to the optimizer to decide and it will only do so if the criterion on "Cancelled" is very filtering, which I doubt since it is probably a boolean...
In the second example#2, you have you yourself found the synthesis.
